# IUrlHelper Url.Action() throwing null parameter exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a web application in .NET Core MVC (.NET 5.0) framework.
I have a class inherited from `ControllerBase (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc)` in which I developed a method which will take `actionName`, `controllerName`, and `port` as parameters and return URL as `Uri` object.

In the method, I am using `UriBuilder` and assigning **Path** through **IUrlHelpler's Url.Action(action, controller)** which is giving me the following error:

**Exception Message:**

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'helper')

**Stack Trace:**

> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.UrlHelperExtensions.Action(IUrlHelper helper, String action, String controller)

**My Code:**

```
public Uri UriUrlBuilder(string actionName, string controllerName, int? port)
        {
            try
            {
                _ = new AppSettingsConfiguration();
                UriBuilder uriBuilder = new()
                {
                    Host = AppSettings.BaseURL,
                    Scheme = "https",
                    Port = (int)port,
                    Path = Url.Action(actionName, controllerName)
                };
                return uriBuilder.Uri;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _ = new LogWriter("Class: Common. Method: UriUrlBuilder.  Error: " + ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

According to Stack Trace logs, it seems like I need to pass IUrlHelper's object as a parameter in Url.Action method. But in actual that method is not taking any parameter like that.

I visited the following links but did not get much help:

[How to use Url.Action() in a class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869222/how-to-use-url-action-in-a-class-file)

[ASP.NET 5 - MVC 6 - Unit Test a Controller that uses Url.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816691/asp-net-5-mvc-6-unit-test-a-controller-that-uses-url-action)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether you have `return view()` in this controller, otherwise the parameter will be not sent back.
2. Try to use the interface [`IUrlHelper.Action()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.action?view=aspnetcore-5.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-iurlhelper-action(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-routing-urlactioncontext)) to create an instance to generate the path.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use context:

```
UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action(actionName, controllerName)
```